# About GCM registrationId in Android App when device is transferred

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing Android App with GCM.

I get registrationId for sending push notification by the following code and then store it in SharedPreferences.

```
registrationId = gcm.register("xxxxx");
```

When my app is transferred from a device to another by backup tool, I guess every data which stored in SharedPreferences are transferred.

Then I think above registrationId is not active in the new device.

Is it true?

If true, what is the best way to solve this problem?

Should I always get the latest registrationId, and then if it is different from the one stored in SharedPreferences, resave the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is true.
"For apps that use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for push notifications, backing up the registration token that Google Cloud Messaging registration returned can cause unexpected behavior in notifications for the restored app. This is because when a user installs your app on a new device, the app must query the GCM API for a new registration token. If the old registration is present, because the system had backed it up and restored it, the app doesn't seek the new token. To prevent this issue from arising, exclude the registration token from the set of backed-up files."
-Taken from developers.android.com

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I exclude only registration token from back-up file programmatically?

Comment: You can exclude set of resources with  exclude tag.

Comment: <full-backup-content>
    <include domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"]
    path="string" />
    <exclude domain=["file" | "database" | "sharedpref" | "external" | "root"]
    path="string" />
</full-backup-content>

Comment: I would like to add here that you should be using InstanceID.getToken to generate your tokens, and you don't have to store these tokens locally, you could just store whether or not you have sent the token to the server. You would still have to exclude sharedpref though.

Comment: @Bedant, Thank you for your reply. I think full-back-up tag is from targetSDKversion 23. For earlier version, what should I do?